# Using chaining to attach values to a empty object, without using call()

Tags: javascript

I have been coding in jQuery for a while now , And one thing that really fainates me about jQuery is the way it is able to chain methods, I just decided to make my own set of chainable methods, In pure js of course and well, It does't do anything useful, have a look:

```
var me = {};

function add() {
  this.color = 'red';
  return this;
}

function value() {
  this.value = 50;
  return this;
}

var s = add.call(me);

console.log(me);
```

What i wanted to achieve was a syntax, like so,

```
me.add().value();  // value should be Object { color: "red" , value : 50 }
```

Well, how do i achieve that kind of syntax ?

As of now i have to use the `call()` to forcefully change the context of the functions `add()` and `value()` , can somebody tell me please ?

**[THIS](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)** article kind of helped me in understanding that it is important to `return this`, but i am still unable to understand how i can use chaining in my scenario as of now.

Any help and advice will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**:: This might sound crazy, but i am already aware of syntax like below:

```
var obj = 
{
    f1: function() { ...do something...; return this;},
    f2: function() { ...do something...; return this;}
}
```

if you observe the above code this indeed will be pointing to the main object(obj) , but what if i have a obj2 ?? got to use `call()` or `apply()` now ? that's not what i want and hence i would like the functions to not be closure's inside the object, but rather independent functions, that can be called on any object, like so:

```
me.add().value();  // value should be Object { color: "red" , value : 50 }
```

Is this possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: Note on the duplicate: The second answer is the one you want.

Comment: @Cerbrus added a edit , please have a look :) might sound crazy , the 2nd answer indeed is an option , but not what i was looking for .

Comment: Make a "class": `var MyObj = function(){ this.f1 = function() { return this; }}`, Initialize it: `var me =  new MyObj()`, Use it: `me.f1().f2()`

Comment: @Cerbrus you can add that as an asnwer ,  if you please :)

Comment: I can't, since it's marked as duplicate.